# What needs to be done in the useMutation hook in order for the returned result to have 'symbol.iterator'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am going tgrough the repo that Tanner [used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seU46c6Jz7E&t=815s) when illustrating react query functionality and its benefits. Basically I am doing it step by step in line with the order of his commits in this [repo](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query-blog-refactor-example). However when I reached the stage of migrating to using react-query from using useEffect and regular fetching mechanisms I got stuck with the following error

> Type 'UseMutationResult<void, unknown, void, unknown>' must have a
> 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

This error occurs when I am trying to use a custom hook `useCreateTransaction`. Implementation of this custom hook looks like following:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query";

export default function useCreateTransaction() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (values) => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/transactions", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });
      // const data = await res.json();
      // return data;
    },
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("transactions");
      // return [createTransaction]
    },
  });
}
```

What I tried to do: to assign returned values of this hook by way of destructuring like so

```
const [createTransaction, { status: createTransactionStatus }] =
    useCreateTransaction();
```

I was expecting to use `createTransaction` to mutate the state on server but instead am seeing this error

> Type 'UseMutationResult<void, unknown, void, unknown>' must have a
> 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

I am not sure if this is helpful: I am using astrobuild for the client and planetscale as the db and cloudflare functions as the backend. Here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/bkyerv/react-query-demo/blob/main/src/hooks/useCreateTransaction.ts)

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting... It's not listed in the [docs](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/useMutation) to return an iterable. It returns an object with a few defined properties.

Comment: @vera. For some reason there is no button for me to mark your answer as the correct one. What a silly mistake I have made=( I followed the 3y.o. tutorial and have not noticed the api had changed. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [createTransaction, { status: createTransactionStatus }] =
    useCreateTransaction();
```

this is the v2 api. The video is almost 2.5 years old. Concepts are still relevant, but apis have changed. Latest version is v4, where it is:

```
const { mutate: createTransaction, status } =
    useCreateTransaction();
```

You're getting that error because you're trying to destruct something as an array that isn't an array.